# How do I setup the api-stub in an ember-cli app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I’m setting up a basic app using ember-cli and am running into trouble with the api-stub with ember-data. I've referenced the api-stub README and have referenced the ember guides, but can't figure out what I'm missing. I’m a bit of a noob, so forgive any obvious oversights on my part.

Here's my setup...

/api-stub/routes.js

```
server.get('/listings', function(req, res) {
  var listing = {
    "listing": [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Sunny 1-bedroom",
      "unit_type": "1br / 1ba",
      "description": "Roomy 1-bedroom apartment in pre-war walkup. Gets great morning light from the south."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Large 2-bedroom",
      "unit_type": "2br / 1.5ba",
      "description": "Roomy 2-bedroom apartment in pre-war walkup. Gets great morning light from the south."
    }]
  };

  res.send(listing);
});
```

/app/adapters/application.js

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

/package.json

```
{
  ...
  "APIMethod": "stub",
  ...
}
```

/app/router.js

```
this.resource('listings', function() {
    this.resource('listing', { path: '/:listing_id' });
});
```

/app/routes/listings.js

```
var ListingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('listing');
    }
});

export default ListingsRoute;
```

/app/models/listing.js

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

var Listing = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  unit_type: attr(),
  description: attr()
});

export default Listing
```

/app/templates/listing.hbs

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<p>{{unit_type}}</p>
<p>{{description}}</p>
```

In console it shows a 404 for …/api/listings and ember inspector in chrome is showing no records.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

As of recently, ember-cli now supports API stubbing. I also got it working with the following example setup (very similar to your original setup):

/app/adapters/application.js

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({namespace: 'api'});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

/app/package.json

```
{
    ...
    "APIMethod": "stub",
    ...
}
```

/app/routes/application.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            foos: this.store.findAll('foo'),
            bars: this.store.findAll('bar')
        });
    },

    setupController: function(controller, models) {
        controller.set('foos', models.foos);
        controller.set('bars', models.bars);
    }
});
```

/app/router.js

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: ENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foos', function() {
        this.resource('foo', { path: '/:foo_id' });
    });

    this.resource('bars', function() {
        this.resource('bar', { path: '/:bar_id' });
    });
});

export default Router;
```

/app/server/routes/foos.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/foos', function(req, res) {
        res.send({
            'foos': [ 
                    ...
             ]
        });
     })
}
```

/app/server/routes/bars.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/bars', function(req, res) {
        res.send({
            'bars': [ 
                    ...
             ]
        });
     })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I asked Stefan Penner about this via Twitter, and here was his response:

[@caretpi](https://twitter.com/caretpi) API stub does not work in cli. We hope to have it integrated soon though

— Stefan Penner (@stefanpenner) [April 1, 2014](https://twitter.com/stefanpenner/statuses/450997168430919680)

There's an issue open on GitHub: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/153

Comment: Issue closed, instead of supporting api-stub, the server has been exposed. https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/568

Answer (score 4):

As of version 0.0.41 use the http-mock and http-proxy blueprints. See my answer [here for using http-mock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25630343/3991812). Use http-proxy like so:

```
>ember g http-proxy projects http://localhost:8080/
```

After applying [this fix](https://gist.github.com/tstirrat/7369faef52f6858caa86) (kudos @tstirrant) to the generated proxy code, it will work as expected. ie. it will proxy localhost:4200/projects to localhost:8080/projects

Update: In version 0.0.46 the generator includes 'the fix' so it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the stub API you need to edit **package.json**.

- Set the **APIMethod** to `stub` to use these express-server stub routes.
- Set the method to 'proxy' and define the **proxyURL** to pass all API requests to the proxy URL, eg. `http://localhost:8000`

**Update - this is my working setup**

`api-stub/routes.js`

```
server.namespace('/api', function() {
  server.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
    res.send([...]);
  });
});
```

`package.json`

```
...
"name": "myapp",
"namespace": "appkit",
"APIMethod": "stub",
"proxyURL": "http://localhost:8000",
"proxyPath": "/api",
...
```

Now, an `ajax` `GET` request to `http://localhost:8000/api/posts` responds with the mock array.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I've updated the question to include package.json, which already had the APIMethod set to stub. As for the second bullet, I saw that instruction in the README as well, but am not clear which method I'm supposed to set to 'proxy' or where for that matter. It makes sense, just not clear where/how to do it.

Comment: Could you expound with the actual line of code and where it goes? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and duplicating the proxyURL and proxyPath above isn't resolving it for me. I've copied and pasted the changes in the api-stub README.md verbatim, and suspect the problem may lie in my proxy settings. In my case, the ember server is running on port 4200. Should the proxyURL be on the same port?